# How to figure out which process uses IO on Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I am using Windows 7 on my laptop and it is really slow - probably because the HDD led is on most of the time. How can I figure out which process (ab)uses the hard drive? On Linux this is usually reflected as the kernel cpu usage, but it doesn't seem to be the case in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Resource Monitor (Start -> search for **resmon**, and then run the `resmon.exe` search result. There are detail views per-process for CPU, HDD, network, and memory.

An alternative is to download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It is a lightweight application that does not require installation. It shows a lot more detail, especially regarding `svchost` child processes. Run this as admin as well to ensure you can see all the processes running.

In Process Explorer, right click-the columns and display the following two columns:

1. I/O Delta Read
2. I/O Delta Write

Then go to View|Update Speed and select '5 seconds'.

You can now sort by the two columns you added to work out which process is performing the most IO.